# Preprint by W. Danielewski, "On the cancellation problem and automorphism groups of affine algebraic varieties," Warsaw, 1989?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Where can I get a copy of the 8-page preprint by W. Danielewski, "On the cancellation problem and automorphism groups of affine algebraic varieties," Warsaw, 1989? It appears to have never been published.  Everyone cites the preprint.

Comment: You might do better asking this on MO.

Comment: Thank you for the preprint.

Comment: @Tri So did you finally get the preprint? Is it accessible somewhere, or could you send me a copy?

Comment: @Jose Brox  I will never give it to you---never! Do you hear me?  Never!

Comment: @Tri I'm also interested in the preprint, how did you manage to get it?